# angularjs ng-repeater dynamically delete data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a situation where users added sample data as shown in figure. How can I add Delete button which deletes particular sample ONLY.  From figure , I want 'Delete Sample 1" to delete Sample 1 records only.

Thanks

[image]

Code triggered when Add Sample button is clicked

$scope.addSample = function () {

```
    $scope.partdetails = [
  {
      "sampleseq": 0,
      "sampleid": 1,
      "attribute": "Height",
      "measureunit": "Centimeter",
      "actualvalue": null,
      "lowerspec": 1.23,
      "upperspec": 3.23,
      "notes": null
  },
  {
      "sampleseq": 0,
      "sampleid": 2,
      "attribute": "Diameter",
      "measureunit": "Inches",
      "actualvalue": null,
      "lowerspec": 1.23,
      "upperspec": 3.23,
      "notes": null
  }
    ];

    $scope.partdetails[0].sampleseq = $scope.sampleCount;
    $scope.partdetails[1].sampleseq = $scope.sampleCount;

    $scope.partdetailsList.push($scope.partdetails[0]);
    $scope.partdetailsList.push($scope.partdetails[1]);

    $scope.sampleCount += 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include a sample of the data structure and the HTML for the view.

Comment: Where you want to add delete button in row or top of the table? Also when user click on delete-1 then you want to remove all samples whose id is 1 ? Is that correct? basic example is here http://jsfiddle.net/crrypdLj/1/

Comment: when I say sample 1 , that means  first 2 top rows. Only these rows needs to be deleted as they belong to sample 1 .  Not all rows. Unfortunately the jsfiddle link deleted single row at a time.

Comment: Where is the button ? in the row or at the top? here is updated sample with single row and with multiple row http://jsfiddle.net/crrypdLj/2/

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in helping me. I was able to resolve the the issue using this link. https://coderwall.com/p/fnp2oq/use-ng-repeat-on-tbody-to-create-summary-rows-for-nested-data

Comment: I added the picture with the solution

Comment: ohh cool may be my understanding was wrong....

Answer (score 0):

This link has the solution just modify the list accordinlgy

https://coderwall.com/p/fnp2oq/use-ng-repeat-on-tbody-to-create-summary-rows-for-nested-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get a new data record without the items that fail a predicate function

Lets say your delete button calls a function called `deleteSample` and passes it a sample id:

**HTML**:

```
... ng-repeat="row in records" ...

<button ng-click="deleteSample(row.sampleid)">Delete sample</button>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.deleteSample = function(sampleId) {
    $scope.records = $scope.records.filter((row)=> {
        return !angular.equals(sampleId, row.sampleid)
    });
}
```

Of course that doesn't solve the issue that you would probably need to remove the rows in your db too.